# Could not find :ARPresto:. Required by: project :unityLibrary Search in build.gradle files

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-library

I am currently integrating a Unity AR project as a library in a native Android Studio project. It is all fine with the exception that when I try to build/run the project in Android Studio I get the exception from the title:

```
Could not find :ARPresto:.
Required by:
    project :unityLibrary
Search in build.gradle files
```

I have no idea why this happens since the unity project seems to be successfully integrated as a library and I can open in the in Android Studio project menu.

This is the build.gradle file of the Unity Library:

```
    allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            flatDir {
                dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
            }

        }
    }
}

// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation(name: 'ARPresto', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'unityandroidpermissions', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'VuforiaEngine', ext:'aar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a' }
        ndk {
            // Default ABI list for this app, can be over-ridden by providing an abiList property
            // e.g. gradle -PabiList=x86 clean assembleDebug
            abiFilters ((project.findProperty('abiList') ?: 'armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a').split(/,\s*/))
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.1'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.ress', '.resource', '.obb'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }
}
```

This is the module and project gradle files of the parent android app:

**Project**

```
   ext {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        flatDir {
//            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
//        }
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.chemistryar"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk{
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','x86'
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation project(path: ':unityLibrary')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

    // unity

    //implementation project(':unityLibrary')
    //implementation fileTree(dir: project(':unityLibrary').getProjectDir().toString() + ('\\libs'), include: ['*.jar'])


    //bottom navigation bar
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Were you finally able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @SarimMehdi The issue is that there is no official way to integrate Unity as a dependency for Android.

Comment: But I see people doing it all the time, there must be a way